# cannot access other controller without index.php in windows live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use my htaccess to remove index.php from the url. Application is working fine when on my pc. I use XAMPP. but when i uploaded into the server it only shown the homepage, i cannot access other controller without index.php in windows live server

Answer (score 2):

Hta access wont work in Windows live server you have to modified web.config file in root folder of your project and add rewrite code under the   part like this . sure it will helps you .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite> 
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.pl" />
                <add value="default.html" />
                <add value="Default.cshtml" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Place this on your **.htaccess** file on the root directory.This solved the issue for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```